# Simplify $\Bigg(\frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{1}{2x}\Bigg)\sqrt{1+\Bigg(\frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{1}{2x^2}\Bigg)^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

How is this integral simplified as shown?

\begin{align}
S &=2\pi \int^3_\frac{1}{2} \Bigg(\frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{1}{2x}\Bigg)\sqrt{1+\Bigg(\frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{1}{2x^2}\Bigg)^2} \mathop{\mathrm{d}x}\\
&= 2\pi\int^3_\frac{1}{2} \Bigg(\frac{x^5}{12}+\frac{x}{3} + \frac{1}{4x^3}\Bigg)\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}
\end{align}

Comment: Since the simplification has nothing to do with the fact that you are integrating, or indeed with anything but rational-function algebra, why the calculus, integration, and definite-integrals tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$\left(\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{1}{2x^2}\right)^2=\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)^2-2\cdot\frac{x^2}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2x^2}+\left(\frac{1}{2x^2}\right)^2=\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)^2-\frac{1}{2}+\left(\frac{1}{2x^2}\right)^2.$$
So when you add $1$, the middle term becomes $+\frac{1}{2}$. Thus 
$$1+\left(\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{1}{2x^2}\right)^2=\left(\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2x^2}\right)^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

$1+(\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{1}{2x^2})=(\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2x^2})^2$. Now you can do it

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Expand the term under the square root. It is a square, namely $(x^8 + 2x^4 + 1)/(4x^4)$. Do you see why ?